# Ninject feature (WhenInjectedInto) equivalent in Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, castle-windsor

This is my first post here, hoping to start also posting more often in the future :)

I have been trying to learn to use Castle Windsor rather than using Ninject but there's one feature I haven't been able to sort of "translate" to use in Windsor, and that is WhenInjectedInto.

Here's one example taken from Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book, with Ninject

```
kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();
kernel.Bind<IDiscountHelper>().To<FlexibleDiscountHelper>().WhenInjectedInto<LinqValueCalculator>();
```

This is a conditional binding, meaing that when it's LinqValueCalculator that is being bound to IValueCalculator, it should use FlexibleDiscountHelper when binding to IDiscountHelper, rather than any other object.

How can I replicate this with Windsor, if it's even possible ?

So far I have:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IValueCalculator>().ImplementedBy<LinqValueCalculator>());
container.Register(Component.For<IDiscountHelper>().ImplementedBy<FlexibleDiscountHelper>());
```

Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use `DependsOn`:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDiscountHelper>()
             .ImplementedBy<FlexibleDiscountHelper>());

container.Register(
    Component.For<IValueCalculator>()
             .ImplementedBy<LinqValueCalculator>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IDiscountHelper, FlexibleDiscountHelper>());
```

There are a number of different ways to specify this dependency, check out [the documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-dependencies.ashx) if this specification isn't exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work as I expected. I will update my question with a more complete example, since I tried a few more things.

Comment: hehe, I finally understood while I was trying to update my example, I was having an hard time to explain my problem because I wasn't fully understanding it, but I got it now. Thanks! This answer is correct. Sadly can't upvote it yet.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

The nearest equivalent to Ninject's `When` would probably be the **[`IHandlerSelector`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Handler-Selectors.ashx)** interface, which allows you to select a given handler based on some predicate, which in the case of the `IHandlerSelector` is the return value of the `HasOpinionAbout` method.

[**Ayende has an example for how HandlerSelectors can be used on his blog.**](http://ayende.com/blog/3633/windsor-ihandlerselector)

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I will have a look later, thanks :)